# substitute single quotes in sed and perl

Tags: regex, perl, sed

Could someone please explain what was happening with these two commands? Why do `sed` and `perl` give different results running the same regular expression pattern:

```
# echo "'" | sed -e "s/\'/\'/"
''
# echo "'" | perl -pe "s/\'/\'/"
'
# sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.5
```

Comment: Sorry, i don't get the above example correctly executed.  Can you double check which shell are you using.  With bash I only get *one* such quote.

Comment: @LuisColorado Hello I tested it again but it's two quotes in the first case. Shell is GNU Bash 4.4.

Comment: you have been answered with the right thing by @shawn below (a gnu sed improvement???), I was using a non GNU sed(1), as my Mac has a `sed(1)` derived from BSD code.  So it didn't show your issue.
Before making such an improvement, GNU guys should check the compatibility issues related to that, and document them with neon lights, directing you to the problem.

Comment: @LuisColorado Well yes I'm on Linux so it's GNU sed. The result is explained as a GNU extension. I think I should add sed version in the question. Thank you for confirming the problem doesn't manifest itself on mac systems.

Comment: Mac OS derives from BSD systems, not from GNU, so many tools don't show same behaviour as GNU's.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using GNU sed, right? `\'` is an extension that acts as an anchor for end-of-string in GNU's implementation of basic regular expressions. So you're seeing two quotes in the output because the `s` matches the end of the line and adds a quote, after the one that was already in the line.

To make it a bit more obvious:

```
echo foo | sed -e "s/\'/@/"
```

produces

```
foo@
```

Documented [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/gnu.html), and in the [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/regexp-extensions.html#regexp-extensions)

Edit: The equivalent in perl is `\Z` (or maybe `\z` depending on how you want to handle a trailing newline). Since `\'` isn't a special sequence in perl regular expressions, it just matches a literal quote. As mentioned in the other answer and comments, escaping a single quote inside a double quoted string isn't necessary, and as you've found, can potentially result in unintended behavior.

Comment: Right on, but I'd also add a comment that it all starts from escaping `'` needlessly

Comment: Re "*Since `\'` isn't a special sequence in perl regular expressions*", More specifically, `\ ` followed by a non-word character (such as `'`) is guaranteed to match just that character in Perl.

Comment: @zdim Actually I was trying to replace `'` with `\'`, but I found I need quite a few escapes: `echo "'" | perl -pe  "s/'/\\\'/"`. This means the replacement word expects `\\'` but not `\'`. Any docs on this?

Comment: @Cyker For one, you don't need to escape `'` in a regex, so `perl -pe "s/'/'/";` (same in sed). Then, if you do, in Perl there is no problem like the one in `sed` (where `\'` has that special meaning in GNU's version), so  `perl -pe"s/\'/\'/"` does the same.  Finally, you can keep `'` for delimiters and use `\x27` for single quote -- `echo "'" | perl -pe's/\x27/quote/'`

Comment: @Cyker Oh, sorry, I see now what you mean ... the problem is the backslash there

Comment: @zdim Well, you got it. So I need a doc confirming `\'` is the same as `'` in a regex (if so), whether it's sed or perl.

Comment: @Cyker If you meant that you have a `'` and want `\'` instead, this isn't too bad: `"s/'/\\'/"`. Or, if there's actually more to do:  `'s/\x27/q(\\).q(')/e'`. With `/e` it evaluates the replacement part as code what may make it easier sometimes to set things straight.

Comment: @Cyker  Re: "_whether it's sed or perl_" -- it's not the same in sed: in GNU's version `\'` is the line-end anchor while `'` is just the literal. In Perl though the `\'` is the same as `'` (escapes have no effect on non-word characters).

Comment: @zdim Basically `\'` means different things in the search word and replacement word, in sed. Just had some fun with this: `echo "foo'foo" | sed "s/foo'foo/bar\'bar/"` and `echo "foo'foo" | sed "s/foo\'foo/bar\'bar/"`. Things are more consistent in perl.

Comment: @Cyker Well, yes -- the difference between Perl and sed for this is in the matching part, where in sed `\'` has the special meaning (in GNU), while in Perl it doesn't.  In the replacement part the `'` and `\'` are the same in both languages.